# Change media-keys shorcuts in cinnamon

Tags: shortcut-keys, cinnamon, gsettings

I've installed cinnamon on Ubuntu and I want to create a setup script. Including hotkeys.
[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174683/custom-global-keybindings-in-cinnamon-via-gsettings) showed me how to add custom key-bindings, great.

But how can I add `'<Super>1'` to the browser (www) key bind?

I can get it with `gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys www`

But I can't figure the format out for the `set`

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/media-keys www "['XF86WWW', '<Super>1']"
```

This above is the format if I "mirror" the custom keys. But that gives an error: `Schema “org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys” is not relocatable (path must not be specified)`

What is the correct format?

Comment: Yes that worked . Can you add this as a regular answer? then I can award the bounty.

Comment: I did try that, but it doesn't give output, nor does it update the hotkey-GUI. So I didn't think it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be resolved by removing the path `/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/media-keys` as said in the error message; so the command must be :

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.media-keys www "['XF86WWW', '<Super>1']"
```